# Problems with nested loops in Python

Tags: python, numpy, nested-loops

I am new to Python and wanted to use it for a university project. I read data from a .csv file, and apply the SVD algorithm on them. Afterwards I want to resize the arrays I get as an output into new arrays as per the project's instructions. The problem arises when I try to sopy the data from one array to the other. Here's some code that produces the same behaviour.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = np.ones((4,5))
test2 = np.zeros((4,3))
i=0
j=0
while i < 4:
    while j < 3:
        test2[i][j] = test[i][j]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

After the nested loops I expect to see the same data on arrays test and test2 but what actually happens is that only the first row gets copied while the rest don't and I have no idea why.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Replace your file read with a hard-coded test case; your posted code fails because we can't read your file.

Comment: Why did you use `while` loops instead of `for`?  That's just one more item to trace.

Comment: as I said I am very new to python so I just went for what was most familiar

Comment: I want to copy the elements only up until the 50th column and I couldn't figure out how to limit the columns I read with a for loop.

Comment: It's *really* helpful to have a concrete example — a miniature version of your existing data. It sounds like you just want a slice of the data in `u`, which shouldn't need a loop. That would look something like `u[: 6036,0:50]` But it's hard to answer for sure because we can't see any of your data.

Comment: move `j=0` inside the `i` loop.  you need to reset it each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of your problem is using the wrong loop type.  You made a very common mistake with using a `while` to do the job of a `for`.

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < 6036:
    while j < 50:
        u_50[i][j] = u[i][j]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

After you're done with the first iteration of the `i` loop, you increment `i` from 0 to 1, and hit the `while j` statement.  However, `j` is still 50, because you failed to reset it.  You need the `j` controls totally within the `i` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 6036:
    j = 0
    while j < 50:
        u_50[i][j] = u[i][j]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Please revisit your tutorial materials and learn to use `for`, so you don't repeat this mistake.

```
for i in range(6036):
    for j in range(50):
        u_50[i][j] = u[i][j]
```

Comment: This is *not* great advice for numpy arrays. You are basically making a slice with nested loops instead of just using `u_50 = u[:6036, :50]` and then perhaps `copy()`ing it if you need a copy.

Comment: I agree that it's not great.  We're trying to fix OP's immediate problem, not serve as a full-range tutorial service.  One (or two) steps at a time ... OP is still confused about basic loops.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and I'll try to provide a  minimal, reproducible example from the get go next time. As I said I am very new to Python, but I wanted to give it a go since I've heard very good things about it, so any extra bit of info helps.